# Bootstrap 3.0 inline forms with validation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've tried to make inline forms work but it seemed that the width of the inputs doesn't stretch to 100% of col-md-x. Not only that, the glyphicon doesn't work because the width doesn't stretch to 100%.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
            <label class="sr-only"></label>
                <select class="form-control" id="add-assessment_questionType">
                    <option value="slider">Slider</option>
                    <option value="radio">Radio Button</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 form-group">
            <label class="sr-only"></label>
            <textarea class="form-control add-assessment_newQuestion" rows="3" id="add-assessment_question" placeholder="Enter Question"></textarea>
        </div>
    <div id="add-assessment_title_color" class="col-md-5 form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="sr-only"></label>
        <input type='text' class="form-control add-assessment_newQuestion" id="add-assessment_optionMaxValue" placeholder="Enter Max Value"></input>
        <span id="add-assessment_optionMaxValue_icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
```

Here is the fiddle (view it at max width to see the "bug"):
http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap's `.form-inline` isn't really intended to be used with columns inside it. According to the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline):

> To use the inline form, you'll have to set a width on the form
>   controls used within.

Alternatively you could use a standard form and put your form controls into a row. See the code below and this example bootply: http://www.bootply.com/MPWi0SUfY5

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only"></label>
          <select class="form-control" id="add-assessment_questionType">
            <option value="slider">Slider</option>
            <option value="radio">Radio Button</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only"></label>
          <textarea class="form-control add-assessment_newQuestion" rows="3" id="add-assessment_question" placeholder="Enter Question"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div id="add-assessment_title_color" class="form-group has-feedback">
          <label class="sr-only"></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control add-assessment_newQuestion" id="add-assessment_optionMaxValue" placeholder="Enter Max Value">
          <span id="add-assessment_optionMaxValue_icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```